# js function getting all values in the fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

The following function is only getting first index amount, while I need all the fields of amount, and find amount type in those fields

```
$("#payment_info").on("change", ".price", function() {
  var amount = $(".amount").val();
  var price = $(this).val();
  var at = $(".amount_type").val();
  if (at === "Percentage"){
    $('.amount').val(amount * 100 / price);
  }
  console.log("hello",price,amount, at);
  }
 );



 #payment_info
            .card.mt-3
              .card-header
                h5 Payment Information
              .card-body
                .row
                  -if company.id == 11
                    .col-md-3
                      = f.input :monthly_rent, label: 'Monthly Rent', input_html: { class: 'maskme', value: "#{contract.monthly_rent unless contract.nil?}" }
                  .col-sm-3
                    -if contract.new_record?
                        = f.input :price, label:'Total Rent', required:true, input_html:{class:'maskme',class:"price", value: "#{unit.market_rent unless unit.nil?}"}
                    -else
                        = f.input :price, label:'Total Rent', required:true, input_html:{class:'maskme',class:"price", value: "#{contract.price unless contract.nil?}"}
                  .col-sm-3
```

amount_input , and amount_type input

```
 .atype.col
= f.input :amount_type ,as: :hidden , input_html:{class:"amount_type"}
= f.input :amount,label: f.index == 0 ? 'Amount' : false, placeholder: 'Amount', disabled: disable, input_html:{class:'amount maskme',class:"amount"}
```

Comment: I assume you have multiple elements with all those classes? If so you need to loop through them and get the `val()` from each one individually. You may also need to use DOM traversal to find the related elements. If you can edit the question to include the relevant HTML we will be able to help you more effectively.

Comment: i have updated the question with HTML.i'm new to javascript , and can't figure out how to do this

Comment: If you have multiple input fields with class `amount` and you want values from all of them using jquery. Then try using this
`let values = [];
$( ".amount" ).each(function(index) {
  values.push($(this).val());
});`

`values` array will have all the values from the different input fields with the class `amount`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can you `document.getElementsByClassName()` to get all elements and apply loop on it.

```
var items = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
  for (var i=0; i < items.length; i++) {
    items[i].val(amount * 100 / price);
  }
```

I hope this will help you.